# Segmentation fault when using argp to parse C arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, gnu

I am trying to use GNU `argp` in order to parse arguments to my C application. My application accepts to optional arguments and a non optional argument. The usage is as follows:

```
<prog-name> <file> [-i <input file>] [-o <output-file>]
```

My program looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <argp.h>

typedef struct {
  char* args[2];
  int silent,verbose;
  char* input_file;
  char* output_file;
} args_t;

int main(int argc, char** argv);
static error_t parse_opt(int key, char*arg, struct argp_state* state);

error_t parse_opt(int key, char*arg, struct argp_state* state) {
  args_t* args = state->input;
  switch (key) {
  case 'o':
    args->output_file = arg;
    break;
  case 'i':
    args->input_file = arg;
    break; 
  case ARGP_KEY_ARG:
    if (state->arg_num >= 2) /* Too many arguments. */
      argp_usage(state);
    args->input_file = arg;
    break;
  case ARGP_KEY_END:
    if (state->arg_num < 2)/* Not enough arguments. */
      argp_usage(state);
    break;
  default:
    return ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  // Resources needed for parameter handling
  char* doc = "";
  char* args_doc = "ARG1 ARG2";
  struct argp_option opts[] = {
    {"output", 'o', "out", OPTION_ARG_OPTIONAL, "The output file to produce"},
    {"input", 'i', "in", OPTION_ARG_OPTIONAL, "The input file to use"},
  };
  struct argp argp = {opts, parse_opt, args_doc, doc};
  args_t args;
  args.silent = 0;
  args.verbose = 0;
  args.input_file = "";
  args.output_file = "";

  argp_parse(&argp,argc,argv,0,0,&args);
}
```

When I run the program I get segmentation fault. Please consider that the doc is not very good and I could not understand much. For example I do not know how to handle the compulsory argument. But, I did never expect a procedure like `argp_parse` to segfault me when arguments are not passed in the right way.

I also checked through `gdb` where the application faults, and it is not `parse_opt`, it is somewhere internally to `argp_parse`. What am I doing wrong? Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argp does not know how many options you have in your array.  It requires the last element of the options array to be all zeros:

```
struct argp_option opts[] = {
    {"output", 'o', "out", OPTION_ARG_OPTIONAL, "The output file to produce"},
    {"input", 'i', "in", OPTION_ARG_OPTIONAL, "The input file to use"},
    {0}
};
```

Comment: At the moment I do not have my computer here. Later I'll try it but makes sense... Now I understand why, in the tutorial, I found that line with all zero elements.